# I need assistance in making my python snakes and ladders game have turns

Tags: python, python-2.7

I made a snakes and ladders game on python, however there is only one problem. My code plays the entire game in one go, but I need to play the game in turns between the 2 players. I have no clue what to do now. pls help.

P.S. I'm sorry if my presentation is really bad, its just that I'm using this for the first time and don't really know what I'm supposed to do/say.

Here's my code:

```
player1 = 0
player2 = 0

a = range(1,8);b = range(8,15)[::-1];c = range(15,22);d = range(22,29)[::-1];e = range(29,36);f = range(36,43);g = range(43,50)
print "Snakes and Ladders game"
print g,'\n',f,'\n',e,'\n',d,'\n',c,'\n',b,'\n',a

def check_for_snakes1_and_ladders1_and_snakes2_and_ladders2(n):
    """This method checks for the presence of snakes or ladders in the board"""
    ladders1 = {4:7,41:44}
    ladders2 = {26:33}
    snakes1 = {9:6,17:14}
    snakes2 = {48:41}
    if ladders1.has_key(n):
        print "You landed on a Bridge, Move Forward 3 spaces"
        n = ladders1[n]
    elif ladders2.has_key(n):
      print "You Landed on a Bridge, Move Forward 7 spaces"
      n = ladders2[n]
    elif snakes2.has_key(n):
      print "Oh No! You landed on an Obstacle, Move Backwards 7 spaces"
      n = snakes2[n]
    elif snakes1.has_key(n):
        print "Oh No! You landed on an Obstacle, Move Backwards 3 spaces"
        n = snakes1[n]
    return n


def roll_dice(r):
  from random import randint
  numbers=(randint(1,6))
  print "You Rolled a :",numbers
  return numbers

while player1 < 49 or player2 < 49:
    print "Its turn of player1\n"
    player1 = roll_dice(player1) + player1
    player1 = check_for_snakes1_and_ladders1_and_snakes2_and_ladders2(player1)
    print "Current status of Player1:",player1,"and Player2:",player2

    if player1 > 49:
        print "Winner of the game is player1"
        break

    print "Its turn of player2\n"
    player2 = roll_dice(player2) + player2
    player2 = check_for_snakes1_and_ladders1_and_snakes2_and_ladders2(player2)
    print "Current status of Player1:",player1," and Player2:",player2

    if player2 > 49:
        print "Winner of the game is player2"
        break
```

Comment: Classes are your friend . I will suggest looking at classes for this . Give it  atry on your own . Some initial guidance . Trying thinking on lines of making a Player Object , with Member Values like Current Position etc and functions like move() , win() , die() etc

Comment: Abhimanyu singh thanks Il llook into it

Comment: You don't ever stop to allow a user input in your code. Try adding `raw_input('Press enter to roll the dice')` after your `'it's the turn of player 1/2'` lines